# how to run sql query on all column data and export result to csv -in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, csv

I made sql queries on an access DB. In datagridview2 i see in the first column the istalled programs in the second how many computers are installed that program.

```
col1   col2
xxxx    1
yyyy    2
zzzz    3

OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
            command2.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT Item_1, count(Item_1)   FROM  (SELECT  Item_1 FROM Audit_data where Category_ID = 500)    group by Item_1 having (count(*)>0)   ";

                   command2.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command2);

            da1.Fill(dt2);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
            dataGridView2.AutoResizeColumns();
```

The datagridview3 contains only the computers name where the programs are installed when the selection is changed on datagridview2:

```
 string selcell = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value);



            OleDbCommand command3 = new OleDbCommand();
            command3.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select distinct Fully_Qualified_Domain_Name from Audit_Data, Computer_master where Item_1= '"+selcell+"'    and category_id=500      and Audit_Data.computer_id = Computer_master.computer_id     ";     

            command3.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command3);

            da3.Fill(dt3);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dt3;
            dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns();
```

And i would like to run these queries to get all software with all installed computer names. I don't know how to run query on all data on col 1 and export it to csv like this.

```
xxxx; 1; qwer_pc
yyyy; 2; asdf_pc;
         qwer_pc
zzzz; 3; asdf_pc;
         qwer_pc;
         yxcv_pc
```

Could anyone help to solve this problem?
Or can i somehow combine the two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than i thought:

```
SELECT distinct Item_1,Fully_Qualified_Domain_Name FROM Audit_data,Computer_master where Category_ID = 500      and    Audit_data.computer_id = Computer_master.Computer_id
```

The CSV export is the following :

```
     string csv = string.Empty;

//Add the Header row for CSV file.
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView4.Columns)
{
    csv += column.HeaderText + ',';
}

//Add new line.
csv += "\r\n";

//Adding the Rows
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        //Add the Data rows.
        csv += cell.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
    }

    //Add new line.
    csv += "\r\n";
}

//Exporting to CSV.
string folderPath = txt_csv_exp_path.Text;
File.WriteAllText(folderPath +txt_exp_file_name.Text +" .csv", csv);

MessageBox.Show("CSV file saved.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await conn.OpenAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);

const string Sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name;";

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();        
using var command = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);        
using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(token);        
dataTable.Load(reader);


var columns = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(c => c.ColumnName);        
var results = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => columns.ToDictionary(column => column, column => row[column]));        
var head_str = string.Join(";", columns.Values)));        
var result_str = string.Join("\r\n", results.Select(t => string.Join(";", t.Values)));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**